# Replace column name with another column item name and delete columns every 6 column in loop

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I have following data: in R, I want to replace column name hits with "advertising"
which is an element of column keyword.I want to do this process in repetition for 100 columns. Once this process is complete. I want to delete every six columns (after hits) for 100 columns.

Here is reproducible code for the data sample given below;

```
hits<- c(89, 93, 97, 86, 82, 83, 84, 76, 87, 87) geo <- c("ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca","ca") time<- c("all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all","all") 
keyword<- c("adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver","adver"
) 
group<- c("web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web","web") 
category<- c(12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12) subject1 <- list(hits = hits,geo = geo,time = time, keyword = keyword, group = group) pt_data <- data.frame(subject1, hits, geo,time, keyword, group, category, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

---

I want if we change the column name "hits" with adver which is item in column "keyword", this process shall repeat for 100 columns or so.
then delete columns, geo,time,keyword,and group repatedly for 100 columns or so.
Please note that hits,geo, time,keyword,group,category, are repeating again starting from hits,...……..

[image: data sample is attached here]

Comment: It will help others to answer your question if you can provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). You can use `dput(head(df))` to provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks, joshpk and https://stackoverflow.com/users/8387242/ari-decter-frain. I have now added an example. Please help.

Comment: in r you can't have column duplicate column names

Comment: deplicate column is not a problem as we change the name of the column and delete others

Answer (score 0):

joshpk is right that your questions should include a reproducible code sample so we can see the exact problem you are having. Still, I think this is what you're looking for?

```
#creating example dataset
x <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=100, nrow=1))
x[1,] <- 1:100
colnames(x) <- paste0("r",1:100)

#colnames part
colnames(x)[seq(4,100,6)] <- x[1,seq(4,100,6)]

#deleting columns part
y <- x[,-(seq(5,100,6))]

#result
y[1,1:6]

r1 r2 r3 4 r6 r7
1  2  3 4  6  7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But my question is a bit different. Please look at it again I have given example now. Like in your example how to make it 7 which is under r7 make it column name in the place of 4 as 7

Comment: I don't understand what you want.